# CPU usage of w3wp suddenly rise high when user force quit browser during request

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, w3wp, w3wp.exe

I'm using an Angular 5 Application to send request to an ASP.NET web API server through an IIS server (version 7.5). 
I can include some base64 encoded image strings into my JSON file. Because of that, my sending request normally takes about 30s to complete. 
Everything is working fine. But then I noticed during the request time, if I shut down the browser ( Safari ), CPU usage of w3wp.exe process on server suddenly raise up from 5% to about 50-60% and will keep raising up forever until I kill it.

=============================

Here is a dump log I found by using Debug Diagnostic Tools:

**Thread 33 - System ID 9708**

```
Entry point   ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+1d
Create time   2018/11/27 11:22:22
Time spent in user mode   0 Days 04:39:44.303
Time spent in kernel mode     0 Days 00:00:23.992
```

This thread is not fully resolved and may or may not be a problem. Further analysis of these threads may be required.

**.NET Call Stack**

**Function**

> System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr,
>   System.Web.RequestNotificationStatus ByRef)
>   System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr,
>   System.Web.RequestNotificationStatus ByRef)

**Full Call Stack**

**Function**

**Source**

```
clr!ExceptionTracker::CallHandler+fd      
clr!ExceptionTracker::CallCatchHandler+90     
clr!ProcessCLRException+31c   
ntdll!RtlpExecuteHandlerForUnwind+d   
ntdll!RtlUnwindEx+539     
clr!ClrUnwindEx+40    
clr!ProcessCLRException+2e9   
ntdll!RtlpExecuteHandlerForException+d    
ntdll!RtlDispatchException+45a    
ntdll!RtlRaiseException+22f   
KERNELBASE!RaiseException+39      
clr!RaiseTheExceptionInternalOnly+2aa     
clr!IL_Throw+10b      
0x000007fe`9996bcb7   
0x000007fe`99969002   
0x000007fe`9996ea9f   
0x000007fe`9996dd5d   
0x000007fe`9996ca63   
0x000007fe`9996b977   
0x000007fe`99969002   
0x000007fe`999677fa   
0x000007fe`999674f5   
0x000007fe`99966f36   
0x000007fe`999664e0   
0x000007fe`999661f1   
0x000007fe`999660d0   
0x000007fe`99965bb0   
0x000007fe`999652be   
0x000007fe`99964cc7   
0x000007fe`99963ef3   
0x000007fe`99963d95   
System_Core_ni+3004fe     
0x000007fe`9930df4a   
0x000007fe`9930d8d6   
0x000007fe`9930a8db   
0x000007fe`99309a9d   
0x000007fe`993018c7   
0x000007fe`990b2b7b   
0x000007fe`990b280e   
System_Net_Http_ni+2cb85      
0x000007fe`990b2053   
System_Net_Http_ni+2ce35      
0x000007fe`990b0c53   
System_Net_Http_ni+2cb85      
0x000007fe`990aeea7   
System_Web_ni+2f5419      
System_Web_ni+9c44e3      
System_Web_ni+2b64f0      
System_Web_ni+2cab1c      
System_Web_ni+2b6fe9      
System_Web_ni+2c8ffb      
System_Web_ni+2b812d      
System_Web_ni+2b7d33      
System_Web_ni+9b2ec2      
clr!UMThunkStub+6e    
webengine4!W3_MGD_HANDLER::ProcessNotification+8e     
webengine4!W3_MGD_HANDLER::DoWork+3a5     
webengine4!RequestDoWork+3fc      
webengine4!CMgdEngHttpModule::OnExecuteRequestHandler+21      
iiscore!NOTIFICATION_CONTEXT::RequestDoWork+233   
iiscore!NOTIFICATION_CONTEXT::CallModulesInternal+174     
iiscore!NOTIFICATION_CONTEXT::CallModules+25      
iiscore!W3_CONTEXT::DoWork+34d    
iiscore!W3_CONTEXT::IndicateCompletion+8c     
webengine4!W3_MGD_HANDLER::IndicateCompletion+5d      
webengine4!MgdIndicateCompletion+22   
System_Web_ni+324c6e      
System_Web_ni+2b82f5      
System_Web_ni+2b7d33      
System_Web_ni+9b2ec2      
clr!UM2MThunk_WrapperHelper+43    
clr!UM2MThunk_Wrapper+60      
clr!Thread::DoADCallBack+13d      
clr!UM2MDoADCallBack+b3   
clr!UMThunkStub+26d   
webengine4!W3_MGD_HANDLER::ProcessNotification+8e     
webengine4!ProcessNotificationCallback+42     
clr!UnManagedPerAppDomainTPCount::DispatchWorkItem+1bc    
clr!ThreadpoolMgr::ExecuteWorkRequest+64      
clr!ThreadpoolMgr::WorkerThreadStart+f5   
clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+86     
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+d    
ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+1d
```

What can I do to prevent this from happening? If my user close browser during request time, I want my IIS server automatically stop this w3wp.exe process.

Comment: Either you follow guides like this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tess/2008/02/22/net-debugging-demos-lab-4-high-cpu-hang/ to further analyze the dumps, or you open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com . SO is not a site to show you step-by-step tutorials on dump analysis.